# How to have an Activity that uses a ScrollView AND keep onTouch method working properly?

Tags: android-activity, android-widget, scrollview, intercept

I have an Activity that populates two views on a ViewFlipper. I added an onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) public boolean method to the Activity. The method is implemented so that when the person taps on the screen the ViewFlipper goes to the next view. It works great but some of the text is too long so I went into my XML file and surrounded the textfield in one of my ViewFlipper views with a linearlayout and then a ScrollView. But now when I'm viewing the fields that are too long and show a scroll bar, I can't display the previous view. The onTouch method in my main activity isn't being executed. I have not been able to figure this out. I've read some posts about implementing or overriding the methods in ScrollView but I don't know where to do this in my activity. Does anyone know how I can program ScrollView to not intercept but keep its ability to scroll the view?

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView myScroll;
myScroll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener){

```
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent touchevent) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        oldTouchValue = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();
        if (oldTouchValue < currentX) {
                       //left swipe
                       return true;

                     }
                     if (oldTouchValue > currentX) {
                       //right swipe
                       return true;
                     }

               return false;

  }
```

}